# How to define a connection string to create local database in the current folder?

Tags: c#, .net, database-connection, connection-string, local-database

My current connection string is:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="myConnectionString"         
         connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=CapacityDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=10"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

This works fine except the fact that the database is created in `C:\Users\currentUser` how do I change this so that it will be created in the same folder where the program runs or define a different location that I choose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing `AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|`

> DataDirectory| (enclosed in pipe symbols) is a substitution string
>   that indicates the path to the database. It eliminates the need to
>   hard-code the full path which leads to several problems as the full
>   path to the database could be serialized in different places.
>   DataDirectory also makes it easy to share a project and also to deploy
>   an application.

quote from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh309441%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Use the AttachDBFilename connection string keyword to add a database
>   to your LocalDB instance. When using AttachDBFilename, if you do not
>   specify the name of the database with the Database connection string
>   keyword, the database will be removed from the LocalDB instance when
>   the application closes.

try to change you connection string like something like this:

```
<add name="myConnectionString"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
    connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFileName=|DataDirectory|\CapacityDatabase.mdf;InitialCatalog=CapacityDatabase;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
```

**EDIT**

|DataDirectory| is a placeholder, that in the case of the ASP.Net MVC template refers to the directory App_Data. This way it is possible to specify a relative path for your db file.
You can define the value for |DataDictionary| like this:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", @"C:\XYZ\App_Data\");
```

but is not possible to use a relative path that point to a location higher in the directory structure.

Comment: And how can I set `DataDirectory` to current folder?

Comment: Your DataDirectory will be appData in your solution, so the best choice